# Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading ng2-gridstack

Tags: angular, npm

I'm just trying to install the ng2-gridstack module on my Angular2 app.
On a fresh install, I run:

```
npm install gridstack (dependency)
npm install ng2-gridstack
```

Just follow the [instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-gridstack), but I get the error as follow:

[image: ng2-gridstack error]

Here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { GridStackComponent, GridStackItemDirective } from 'ng2-gridstack';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { UserComponent }  from './components/user.component';
import { AboutComponent }  from './components/about.component';
import { routing }  from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, routing ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, UserComponent, AboutComponent, GridStackComponent, GridStackItemDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my system.config.js

```
packages: {
  app: {
    'ng2-gridstack': {
        main: './ng2-gridstack.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    main: './main.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js',      
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
  ...
```

Tried cache clean, update to the latest version of angular, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to have `jquery` and `lodash` imported into your application as well in order to run `ng2-gridstat`. ng2 gridstat is compiled of `@angular/core` and `gridstat.js` according to the docs you must have both as a requirement in order to run `gridstat.js` found [here](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js#usage). Here is a plunker of it imported correctly [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LMbJx0sk3qDqL4yja9RL?p=preview)

NOTE: in the plunker I just imported using CDN's here

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

you may have to go to the jquery and lodash docs to find out how to import them correctly in your application.